# Regular Expression for xml element

Tags: regex

I have an xml in the form of a string. Let's say that the element name is TestDate and the date is the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. So in other words `<TestDate>1950-03-31</TestDate>`.

How do I find this.

Lets say I have string xml;

xml contains the element TestDate. I want to get that using a regular expression.

```
string regularExpression = @"";
Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpression , RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

What should be going in for regular expression.

Comment: Your syntax and object references imply you are using C#, but please specify what language you are using in a tag or the question or both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want search data in that element only than itshould be

```
<TestDate>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}</TestData>
```

Another aproach is to use XPath.  Load xml string in XmlDocument and extract all similar nodes.  Below code will return all TestDate Nodes.

```
XmlNode[] nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TestDate");
```

Comment: I want to get the whole element and also its content.

Comment: Your regex specifies matching of unbalanced tags (if used verbatim), due to a typo, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This should match your Date: `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

if you can use Perl-RegEx-Syntax, you can use `\d` instead the `[0-9]`

Comment: `\d` works for _almost_ every flavor of regex, but as specified in a comment to another answer, the expression should match the whole tag, not just a date